# How do a play a midi note with a determined duration

Tags: ios, swift, midi, coremidi

To play I'm using a AVAudioUnitSampler:

```
            sampler.stopNote(note, onChannel: channel)
```

But to stop I don't wanna use:

```
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(
                deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(0.7 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            {
               sampler.stopNote(note, onChannel: channel)
            }
```

What's a better solution?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using AVMIDIPlayer? If so you should state that, perhaps in the title of your question

Comment: I'm using AVAudioUnitSampler, but I'm open to alternative ways

Answer (score 3):

You can create a MusicSequence and each event in it will be scheduled by a MusicPlayer.

You can use AVMIDIPlayer, but you need to convert the MusicSequence into Data since it doesn't grok MusicSequence directly.

If you want to emulate note on via a button press and note off via button release, then use MusicDeviceMIDIEvent.

```
let status = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(midisynthUnit, noteCommand, noteNum, velocity, 0)
```

You might want to read [this](http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/the-great-avaudiounitsampler-workout/) for more info on using AVAudioUnitSampler.

Comment: The example is not what I'm looking for because I would like to set a predetermined duration to the note. I tried using a MusicSequence and a MusicPlayer but I'm getting an important latency. Any tips on that?